# RegEx, select anything thats not in brackets

Tags: regex

In RegEx, how would I select anything thats not in brackets:

E.g.

`Xxxxxxx (01010101)` would return `Xxxxxxx` ?

Thanks!

Comment: you could always just *remove* everything that matches `\([^)]+\)`

Comment: @David: `\\([^)]+\\)` is necessary - SO comment formatting obviously removed the backslashes...

Comment: @Smickie: Please provide more examples. The most important question is: Could parens be nested? With arbitrary nesting like `Keep this (remove this (and this (and this too)))` a regex solution is impossible in most regex implementations.

Comment: @Tim: surely, you're joking. My answer deals w/ this example w/o any problems. Just add the lazy quantifier

Comment: @SilentGhost: I didn't say anything about your solution. Misunderstanding?

Comment: @Tim: I was referring to *a regex solution is impossible*.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: indeed, I wasn't aware of the comment formatting... i guess I'm not habitually writing too much code in comments. And I didn't notice it in the result either. Oh well, thanks for fixing.

Comment: @SilentGhost: OK, right. Of course, if something like `Keep this (remove this (and this (and this too))) but keep this` comes along (which is why I asked Smickie for more examples - I should have used this example instead) regexes will blow up.

Comment: @SilentGhost: Your first example converts `(foo(bar)baz)` to `baz)`, which is presumably not what was intended, and adding laziness `\([^)]+?\)` doesn't make any difference. @Tim is correct, correct behaviour with arbitrary parenthesis nesting is impossible in most regex implementations.

Comment: @psmears: no, the code posted in my answer just doesn't match your input. Because it wasn't intended to.

Comment: @Tim: I'm still not getting it, sorry. `re.sub('\(.+\)', '', 'Keep this (remove this (and this (and this too))) but keep this')`? Of course, more complicated cases won't be handled properly, it just doesn't seem relevant to this particular question.

Comment: @SilentGhost: Sorry, my reply was mixed up, "your" was referring to the solution in the first two comments above, which aren't actually yours! But the point remains - some cases aren't handled (by *any* regular expression) - and hence Tim's question was, "What cases *do* need to be handled?"

Comment: @SilentGhost: I do get your point, and it's obvious that we don't know what @Smickie really wants. `Keep (toss) keep (toss) keep` will fail with your regex - but that might be perfectly alright. As long as Smickie is not responding with a better spec, I think this discussion is quite unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the existing sample, this will do:

```
(.+) \(
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\([^)]*\)` as a delimiter, either in `split`, or a `java.util.Scanner`, etc, or just use it to replace with `""`.

In Java:

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
        "abc(xyz)def(123)".split("\\([^)]*\\)"))
    ); // prints "[abc, def]"
    System.out.println(
        "abc(xyz)def(123)".replaceAll("\\([^)]*\\)", "")
    ); // prints "abcdef"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python:

```
import re
def removeparens(inputstring):
    return re.sub(r"\([^)]*\)", "", inputstring)
```

will provide this functionality under the condition that parens are never nested.